# Blazor sidebar menu not reaching bottom of page after expanding menu

Tags: html, css, blazor

I have a sidebar menu on my Blazor application that has an expandable portion when you click on one of the menu options. When you click this option, "maintenance", it adds a few more options to the menu right below the maintenance option. However, when it does this it also pushes everything below it down and adds a scrollbar to the page. This would be okay except for the fact that the items that get pushed down the sidebar go past the point that the sidebar styling goes to. I've included a picture to show what I mean by this - [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmEtq.png). I was hoping there is a way to force the sidebar to always go to the bottom of the page even if the page gets expanded. Here is my code for the page.

```
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Degrade Web</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="enterData">
                <span class="oi oi-tablet" aria-hidden="true"></span>Enter Data
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="deleteUnit">
                <span class="oi oi-circle-x" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete Unit
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        @if (isAdmin) 
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" id="navLink" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
                    <span class="oi oi-signpost" aria-hidden="true"></span>Maintenance
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            @if (expandSubNav)
            {
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="addDimension">
                        <span class="oi oi-resize-both" aria-hidden="true">add Dimension</span>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="addGrade">
                        <span class="oi oi-circle-check" aria-hidden="true">add Grade</span>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="addSpecie">
                        <span class="oi oi-dial" aria-hidden="true">add Specie</span>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="addSeasoning">
                        <span class="oi oi-dashboard" aria-hidden="true">add Seasoning</span>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="lookupTables">
                        <span class="oi oi-magnifying-glass" aria-hidden="true">Lookup Tables</span>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            }
        }
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="comparison">
                <span class="oi oi-eye" aria-hidden="true"></span>Comparison
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="summary">
                <span class="oi oi-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>Summary
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="unitHistory">
                <span class="oi oi-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>Unit History
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="form">
                <span class="oi oi-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>Form
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="trend">
                <span class="oi oi-graph" aria-hidden="true"></span>Trend
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="percents">
                <span class="oi oi-fork" aria-hidden="true"></span>Percents
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="piecesByMill">
                <span class="oi oi-layers" aria-hidden="true"></span>Pieces by Mill
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="reasonsByWeek">
                <span class="oi oi-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>Reasons by Week
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="reasons">
                <span class="oi oi-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></span>Reasons
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="category">
                <span class="oi oi-beaker" aria-hidden="true"></span>Category
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private bool expandSubNav;
    private bool isAdmin = false;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
    {
        if (isAdmin) // If this user is an admin, force an update of the page
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            isAdmin = true;
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the css

```
.navbar-toggler {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.top-row {
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.oi {
    width: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    top: -2px;
}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

    .nav-item:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item:last-of-type {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item ::deep a {
        color: #d7d7d7;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 3rem;
    }

.nav-item ::deep a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    color: white;
}

.nav-item ::deep a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapse {
        /* Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens */
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can fix this by adding `overflow-y: auto;` to the `.sidebar` style in

**MainLayout.razor.css**:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /* Add this line */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

(Assuming you  are using the default `MainLayout.razor` and `MainLayout.razor.css` from the Blazor template)